# How do I LOL? Or is it just an April Fools Prank?

Tags: tiny-tower

In Tiny Tower today I noticed a new mission **April Fool's 2012** which requires **225 LOL**. However I can't seem to click on it. Further after I try to click on it, I can't seem to click on any other missions either. I can still click the red X to get out of the missions screen.

Is there a way to complete this mission? I do have a comedy club, and I've been stocking LOLs.

Edited to add: I am using the Android Version.

Comment: If you are playing on Android I believe it is glitched, because it only shows you need the LOL's and it is not clickable. Or Tiny Tower is trolling us.

Comment: Weird, it definately requires Trick Shots on iOS. Try stocking those and see if the mission accepts those.

Comment: @BenBrocka The Android one has been glitchy since day 1, so I don't doubt it works on the IOS version.

Comment: I mean try getting the Trick Shots just to see if it works, it might just be bugged in how it displays.

Comment: Well for me at least I can't even click the mission on Android. It just doesn't respond.

Comment: You have to Laugh Out Loud.

Comment: It's glitchy and displaying this way for me as well (on Android). I thought it might just be NB playing an April Fool of us, but no? Hope to see it fixed.

Comment: So it appears it's just a prank/bug for Android users! I'll mark as correct either answer if you edit to include appropriate Android info (as gleaned from the comments above!)

Comment: yea, on the android version, it doesn't show the need for trick shots at all. That maybe the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

April Fools 2012 is a new mission, which requires 225 LOL's (from the Comedy Club) and 1350 Trick Shots (from the Billiard Hall).

Once you tap this mission, you should be given the option to Decline or Accept.  If this isn't working for you, try resetting the game by removing it from your currently running apps.

If that doesn't work, be sure that your Tiny Tower is the latest version (v1.5.2 for iPhone).

On the iPhone v1.5.2 version of Tiny Tower, this mission works fine and is acceptable.  On the Android version, it's not click-able; this is probably a bug with that version.

Comment: There was a bug with the Android version where it would glitch because the Billiard Hall wasn't yet available for the Android version. This has since been fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The April Fool's 2012 Mission requires the following:

225 LOLs (Comedy Club)

1350 Trick Shots (Billard Hall)

When you open up the missions menu and scroll to the bottom, check to see if that mission has already been accepted.  If it has, the text of *April Fool's 2012* will be green.

I have just tested this, and it doesn't seem to be a prank(I was able to accept it).  To complete the mission, just stock those items - just like every other mission.